# Excel regex: Delete all content after last group

Tags: regex

I have CSV file with breadcrumb (prestastop products)

I want to delete the content after last separator (product name), my structure is:

col1|col2|col3|product

I can delete with simple regex, problem is that number of separators is not always the same so for example `([^|]+/[^|]+/[^|]+/[^|]+|).*` wont work.

Is there any way to do it with one regex?

I want:

```
col1|col2|col3|product
col1|col2|col3|col4|product
col1|col2|col3|col5|product
```

to become

```
col1|col2|col3
col1|col2|col3|col4
col1|col2|col3|col5
```

I think the simple way would be to read from right to left and not left to right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex to match the last part including the `|` symbol. Just replacing the matched characters with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Regex:

```
\|[^|]*$
```

REplacement string:

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*)\|.*
```

Try this.Replace by

`$1`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/12